how does powershell recognize a path that contains spaces and brackets
I have the following problem. I have a ps1-script which takes a path as parameter and then should check if the path exists. if the path has no spaces and / or brackets like for example “G:\Program Files\Utilities\SendTo2024\testPath1” the code gives the desired result.
However, if the code has brackets and / or spaces, such as in
“G:\Programs\Utilities\SendTo2024\testPath1\test folder[9]t 0p” the path is not recognized and it does not give the expected result.
This is my Powershell script:
# Script name: Check-PathExistence.ps1

param (
[string]$Path
)

write-host $Path

if (-Not (Test-Path $Path)) {
    Write-Host "The path '$Path' does not exist."
} else {
    Write-Host "The path '$Path' exists."
}

I tried two paths. Important both paths are correctly written and exists. The inputs in the shell were executed by the terminal in the working directory where the script is located. the input/otput looks like this :
Input1:
PS G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\> .\\check_if_path_exists.ps1 -path "G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\\ordner1"

Output1:
G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\\ordner1
The path 'G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\\ordner1' exists.

Input2:
PS G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\> .\\check_if_path_exists.ps1 -path "G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\\test ordner\[9\]t 0p"

Output2:
G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\\test ordner\[9\]t 0p
The path 'G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\\test ordner\[9\]t 0p' does not exist.
PS G:\\Programme\\Hilfsprogramme\\SendTo2024\\testPath1\>

I excepted for bot paths a "The pathh .. exists". So is there any function or other possibility in powershell, that recognizes also paths with brackets and or spaces?

You need to use -LiteralPath

Most provider cmdlets in PowerShell have 2 (mutually exclusive) path parameters - -Path and -LiteralPath.
-Path is usually the default, and assumes that the path provided is a valid glob pattern - meaning PowerShell will request that the underlying provider try and expand wildcards and resolve matching paths.
Since PowerShell treats [9] as a single-character wildcard descriptor, the [ and ] are never actually recognized as part of the path itself.
To disable wildcard expansion in paths, simply use the -LiteralPath parameter instead:
Test-Path -LiteralPath $Path

